# PostGIS Optimization - Group spatially close entities physically on disk

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, performance

I'm working on my first PostGIS database and was hoping to find some performance gains for live rendering.

I'm rendering a map directly from a PostGIS (9.1, 2.0) db that contains an import of OSM data (using imposm3). Most importantly, my roads table is about 30GB and it's rendering a bit slower than I would like. In the future, I'll be using generalized alternatives to the fully detailed roads table at higher zoom levels, but for now I just have it rendering at reasonably low zoom levels. I've already taken note of some PostGIS-specific tuning suggestions and these have made a nice impact on performance.

My question is if it would be feasible and worthwhile to reorganize how the entities in my roads table are stored on disk. For example, I would imagine that if I'm querying a neighborhood-sized area and the enclosed entities are on the same physical disk page, performance would be much better than if they were ordered based on OSM submission order (which I fear they are now). I'm wondering if there are any utilities or suggested means of reordering the entities on disk.

Alternatively, would I perhaps benefit from creating new smaller tables spatially split from the larger, 30GB table?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Half out of stubbornness and half out of curiosity, I went ahead and ran the `CLUSTER table ON hash_index` and this ended up making my table's performance *slightly worse*. After doing quite a bit of searching and learning, I came to the realization that **the first thing one should do every single time is `EXPLAIN query`**. Ended up that there was some weirdness with the types and my queries weren't even using the index.

I'm adding this mostly as a PSA to anyone who might wind up here searching for the clustering solution: **check that your indexes are correct and run `explain` to make sure they're being used**.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Putting things closer on disk is likely to make, at best, a minute amount of improvement. Slow performance in databases typically results from not adding indexes, or not adding the right indexes, or not using them correctly. A spatial (rtree) index and appropriate query may help a lot. In your case, querying the database might not be the slow part - perhaps you're not caching the rendered results, or using a slow render. If you can edit your question to show the specific database structure, and the query you think is slow, perhaps we can provide a useful answer.

Comment: You say the "rendering" is slow, but how are you rendering? (Is that a silly question?)

Comment: The rendering bit isn't my domain (yet), I was just wondering if this would be an obvious quick improvement to the actual storage before I even optimization on the other side. Based on the information from @BradHards and Paul Ramsey I understand that the clustering won't likely have a significant impact. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends, naturally. If your rendering only has to spatially scan a "few" (thousands) records to draw, then physical clustering might help, a bit. However, if your rendering has to scan 100s of thousands of records (classic scenario: find me all the highways in this square, but ignore the local roads) then clustering won't make much difference, whereas pre-sorting your data into scale-appropriate types will (highways table, arterials table, etc).

To cluster simply, just:

```
CLUSTER mytable USING myspatialindex;
```

For a cluster with a slightly stronger guarantee of spatial homogeneity:

```
CREATE INDEX myhashidx ON mytable (ST_GeoHash(geom));
CLUSTER mytable USING myhashidx;
```

This uses a quad-tree breakdown to cluster, which helps guarantee that "near" things are near, in a way the more generic r-tree under the standard spatial index does not.

Comment: The cluster command was exactly what I was looking for so I'll take note of that in the future. Based on your suggestions however, I understand that this probably won't make a huge impact on my performance. Thanks!